# Dropdown option "selected" not showing in bootstrap / VueJS

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

Running sails 1.0 app with Vuejs front end with bootstrap and trying to show a selected "option" in a dropdown but it doesn't show as selected when the page renders. I have tried both `<option selected>ounces</option>` and `<option selected="selected">ounces</option>`

HTML:

```html
<!-- ... -->
<div class="col">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select v-bind:id="'ingredient' + index + 'Units'" class="form-control" v-model="newRecipeFormData.ingredients[index].units">
      <option selected>ounces</option> <!-- not showing as selected -->
      <option>grams</option>
      <option>pounds</option>
      <option>kilograms</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot 1:
[image: Selected not showing]

Where should I look for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set the "selected" value in the Vue model, since it is binded by `v-model`

In my js:

```js
  data: {
    recipes: {},

    newRecipeFormData: {
      recipeName: '',
      recipeNotes: '',
      ingredients: [
        { name: '', weight: '', units: 'ounces' },
        { name: '', weight: '', units: 'ounces' },
        { name: '', weight: '', units: 'ounces' },
        { name: '', weight: '', units: 'ounces' },
        { name: '', weight: '', units: 'ounces' },
        { name: '', weight: '', units: 'ounces' }
      ]
    },
    //…
    syncing: false,
    cloudError: '',
    //…
    recipesModalVisible: false,

  },
```

Now it's showing correctly:

[image]